# Angular ngfor , only displayed a record

Tags: arrays, angular

***Hi,
data array displaying on console. but only a record display on view.***

```
users: any[]=[];


ngOnInit(): void {
     this.YukIlan();
}
YukIlan() {
    let controller = this;
    this.orient.command(
      "select * from login",
      function (data) {
        let body = data.json();
        let result = body.result;
        result.forEach((x: any) => {
          controller.addtoUser(x);
        });
      },
      function (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    )   }   addtoUser(Data: any) {

    this.users  = [{
        mobilno : Data.mobilno,
        sifre : Data.sifre,
        rid: Data["@rid"]
    }]
    console.log(this.users)

  }


}
```

views code:

```
<ul><li *ngFor="let item of users">
                        {{item.mobil}} 
                    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pushing data in users array wrong!
This is how you do it:

```
addtoUser(Data: any) {
    this.users  = [{
        mobilno : Data.mobilno,
        sifre : Data.sifre,
        rid: Data["@rid"]
    }]
    console.log(this.users)
}
```

but this is the right way

```
addtoUser(Data: any) {
    this.users.push({
        mobilno : Data.mobilno,
        sifre : Data.sifre,
        rid: Data["@rid"]
    });
    console.log(this.users)
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Great! Can you please upvote my answer and accept it as final answer, it means a lot to me? Thank you!